# Load HTML5 file to HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, load, createjs, flash-cc

I want to create an Apps with Flash CC and createJS.

It's just a 'presentation slide' apps. I want in my apps have  a `Master Slide` canvas file (e.g `MasterSlide.html`), it will contain any other slides from external html file (e.g `slide1.htlm, slide2.html ... etc`).

The problem is, how can I load external slides file to `MasterSlide.html` with createJS (in Actionscript you can use `loader` to load external swf)? If you have any solutions I would appreciated it.

Answer (score 2):

You can load the JavaScript file generated by Flash CC (the easiest way is to use PreloadJS), and then instantiate the "stage" MovieClip (named after the Flash file).

```
var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
queue.on("load", handleComplete);
queue.loadFile("MySlide.js");

function handleComplete(event) {
    var exportRoot = new lib.MySlide();
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
}
```

Unfortunately, it is not quite this simple:

1. This will not preload any images or audio. You would have to do that first. The exported HTML that Flash generates should show you how that goes.
2. All libraries are currently stored on a `lib` namespace, so you would either have to change this in the Flash export settings (per file), or manage it yourself. One way we have done this is to re-assign the `lib` object after the file is loaded, and then set it to null.

Here is a quick sample:

```
function handleComplete(event) {
    myModules[currentModuleId] = lib;
    lib = null; // Wipe this, it gets auto-created the next time a module loads.
}
```

We have used this approach with great success. It is much more manual than the Flash Loader, but it can be done.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much Lanny. I know there is no easy way to do that, but I will try to do it. I really appreciated your help.

Comment: @Lanny - thanks for this code... works nicely to load external libs. Although having a problem with a loaded MC's children when going to the second frame - they are undefined, while the first frame's children can still be referenced : I have a question here for it, I would really appreciate some help! : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552894/undefined-children-in-second-frame-of-externally-loaded-movieclip

Comment: Currently in animate, if you instantiate a clip, its children aren't immediately available. You can get around this by calling `clip.gotoAndStop(0)` to force an update. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Lanny... I've updated the question (created a new one), as I found this issue also occurs regardless of whether the MC is instantiated from a loaded lib - gotoAndStop(0) doesn't make a difference unfortunately. | My new question is here (if you fancy a read ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566953/createjs-movieclip-children-doesnt-update-after-gotoandstop

Comment: Thanks, this helped me very much.

Comment: No worries! Note that libraries in Animate 2017+ are no longer stored on global `lib` object, and use an ID-based lookup. This was made to get around this limitation.

Comment: @Lanny your example helped me to replicate old good AS2's SWF in SWF loadMovie functionality, you just need to get child's "lib" with that ID and it's encapsulated  :)

Answer (score 0):

its magic you can load another file in one html file

replace webcode with folder directory code . and it will work and it will load to your stage

```
man.addEventListener('click', fl_MouseClickHandler_2);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event)
{
window.open("http://graphicscoder.org/", "_self");
}
```

so i have replaced the flash cc export with my folder directory file . its magic that file loads in stage when i click in the "man" movieclip in the stage . its like loading another .swf to one .swf in as3 . more easy . really you can make large elearning/game project with many stages using createjs .

```
man.addEventListener('click', fl_MouseClickHandler_2);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event)
{
window.open("akun/cuen.html", "_self");
}
```