# CreateJS : MovieClip.children doesn't update after gotoAndStop()

Tags: createjs, animate-cc

CreateJS (2015.11.26) via Animate CC (16.0.0.112)

Structure :

```
root
 - myContainer
     - frame 0 -> btn_0
     - frame 1 -> btn_1
```

First frame of root contains following code :

```
var self = this;
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", initScreen);

function initScreen() {
    createjs.Ticker.removeEventListener("tick", initScreen);
    self.myContainer.gotoAndStop(1);
}

this.myContainer.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log("Button 0 : "+self.myContainer.btn_0);
    console.log("Button 1 : "+self.myContainer.btn_1);
});
```

The result is :

```
[Log] Button 0 : [MovieClip]
[Log] Button 1 : undefined
```

And when iterating through `self.myContainer.children`, only `btn_0` exists.

So `self.myContainer.children` is not being updated when playing through the frames.

Seems like a bug, as I can't find any documentation around this... but I'm surprised that I can't find anyone else who's had this issue.

Any help much appreciated.

(Issue raised here : https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/848)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because both buttons use the same symbol.
In AnimateCC, choose btn_1 and change its "instance of", by swapping-duplicating to a new symbol.

This logged for me:

```
Button 0 : [MovieClip (name=null)]
Button 1 : [MovieClip (name=null)]
```

Comment: Thanks Saariko... that must have taken a while to discover that workaround! Unfortunately it won't work brilliantly for me, as the example above is an extract from a project where I have lots of buttons across lots of frames. My current solution is to use a different MC per view instead of a different frame per view.